# Delphi: Detecting mouse wheel button press

Tags: delphi

With regards to the TMemo component, I cannot find a way to detect when the user has released the WHEEL button on their mouse.  The standard OnMouseUp event do not respond to a mouse's wheel button.

[image: Mouse wheel button scroll glyph]

Comment: It is generally (I think) configured as a *middle button*, in which case there should be no problem. Perhaps your mouse is doing something else..

Comment: Something else, or nothing at all. Does the button work in other applications? If so, what does it do?

Comment: Either tag a specific delphi version, or none at all. Don't just tag lots of them for no good reason.

Comment: Correction: The OnMouseDown *IS* triggered, however, the OnMouseUp does not trigger when one is using the "hold the mouse wheel button down" and "move the contents up or down (vertical scrolling)".  When you see that little circle glyph with the up and down arrows in it, the OnMouseUp event does not get detected when the user lets go of the mouse wheel button (see image attached to original question).

Comment: @user - I edited your question to reflect your correction in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

That little circle with up-down arrows is the *panning window* of the VCL that provides the scrolling functionality when the middle button is pressed.

The default panning window, `TPanningWindow`, captures the mouse in its `StartPanning` method to be able to follow mouse movements, and does not release it until panning is stopped - that's due for another click. That's why the memo never receives the middle button up message, hence the `OnMouseUp` event is not fired.

You can detect the button up message before it is dispatched to the panning window, in an `OnMessage` handler of the 'Application'. Below sample code is in an `OnMessage` event handler of a `TApplicationEvents` component, tests if the message is retrieved when the panning window is panning for a 'Memo1'.

```
uses
  imouse;

procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if (Msg.message = WM_MBUTTONUP) and Assigned(Mouse.PanningWindow) and
    (Mouse.PanningWindow.HandleAllocated) and
    (Msg.hwnd = Mouse.PanningWindow.Handle) and
    (Mouse.PanningWindow is TPanningWindow) and
    (TPanningWindow(Mouse.PanningWindow).PanControl = Memo1) then

  // perform what's required

end;
```

---

Alternatively, you can register your own panning window class with the `Mouse.PanningWindowClass` which could notify it's pan control for certain messages. Here is an example:

```
uses
  imouse;

type
  TMyPanningWindow = class(TPanningWindow)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Msg: TMessage); override;
  end;

{ TMyPanningWindow }

procedure TMyPanningWindow.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Msg.Msg = WM_MBUTTONUP) and (Assigned(PanControl)) then
    PanControl.Perform(Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Mouse.PanningWindowClass := TMyPanningWindow;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, however, the imouse.pas unit is not available with Delphi 7.

Comment: @user - You're welcome! There were all sorts of Delphi tags on the question before they were cleared away :) I tested the above code with D2007, D7 is so old now that there are many differences with the current product. You should tag the question with a specific version if you have to run the code on that version. If you have to run the code on many versions, mention that requirement in the question itself (in which case I probably wouldn't bother looking into it).